# Destructor in Objective-C++

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c++

I have an objective-C++ class which contain some honest C++ object pointers.

When the Obj-C++ class is destroyed does it call dealloc immediately? If so, then is the best way to destroy the C++ class by putting

```
delete obj
```

in the dealloc method?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I presume when you say "Obj-C++ class" you mean an Objective-C class that happens to contain some C++ classes.

Objective-C classes don't call dealloc when they're destroyed; they're destroyed by having the dealloc message sent to them.

With that bit of pedantry out the way, if your init method instantiates obj then, yes, call `delete obj` in the dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc {
  delete obj;
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: ARC forbids sending a dealloc message - no need to call `[super dealloc]` when using ARC as answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292119/custom-dealloc-using-arc-objective-c)

Comment: @benjineer ARC wasn't released yet when this answer was written, but you are correct that `[super dealloc]` is not compatible with ARC.

Answer (score 8):

As a supplement to Frank Shearar's correct answer, provided you are using the OSX 10.4 or later SDK (and you probably are; though I'm not sure about the iPhone runtime here) you can also include C++ members of Objective-C classes, i.e. without resorting to a pointer. The problem in earlier versions of the OSX SDK was that the constructor and destructor of the C++ member simply would not get called. However, by specifying the `fobjc-call-cxx-cdtors` compiler option (in XCode it is exposed as the setting `GCC_OBJC_CALL_CXX_CDTORS`), the ctor and dtor will get called. See also [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html), a bit down that page.

Comment: Also works when you need to store a pointer as long as you wrap it e.g. in a `std::unique_ptr`