# Calling a method when the application is called from background

Tags: objective-c, ios, background, uiapplicationdelegate

In applications like Foursquare when I click the Home button the application goes to background. Then when I click on its icon, it loads back the content on the screen.

When I send my app to background and then I recall it back, it doesn't load back the content to the screen. I have entered my code in the `viewDidAppear` method but it is not executed.

How is it possible to load the application content when it becomes active?

Comment: Read the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3

Answer (score 5):

You need to respond to `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` or `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` or the equivalent `UIApplication` notifications. The `UIViewController` lifecycle calls like `viewDidAppear` aren't triggered by app lifecycle transitions.

Comment: This is already in my AppDelegate. So just adding the code there worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

smparkes suggestion is right. You could register for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` or `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`. These notifications are called after those method (the ones smparkes wrote) are called. In the handler for this notification do what you want. For example in `viewDidLoad` for your controller register the following notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(doUpdate:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Do not forget to remove in `dealloc`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Finally, `doUpdate` method could be the following

```
-(void)doUpdate:(NSNotification*)note
{
    // do your stuff here...
}
```

I suggest you to read [UIApplicationDelegate class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). In particular read about **Monitoring Application State Changes**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using ARC, so do i still have to dealloc it ? and why ?

Comment: You should.For more info read this [stackoverflow topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372841/removing-a-nsnotificationcenter-observer-in-ios-5-arc). In this other [stackoverflow topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469209/objective-c-where-to-remove-observer-for-nsnotification) instead the explanation why you should remove it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to listen to UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,here is the ObjC code that might help you.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

    // custom code goes here.
}];
```