# Suddenly "Potential leak of an object"

Tags: ios, xcode, textview, release, memory-leaks

I've been building and doing all sorts of stuff here using the xcode. It never complained about "leak problems". It has just started since I tried to insert ShareKit.

So.. I removed all traces of ShareKit and 11 entries of "Potential leak of an object" appeared.

Here is one example which is happening with a textView:

file.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iAd/iAd.h"
#import "Oracao.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface DetalhesOracaoViewController : UIViewController{
    Cclass *cclass;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Cclass *cclass;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *tWeekDay;

@end
```

file.m

```
...
@synthesize tWeekDay;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.tWeekDay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° day - %@", cclass.dia, cclass.dia_semana];
}

#pragma mark dealloc
-(void)dealloc {
    [tWeekDay release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Any ideas of what could be done?
Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is another leak that I couldn't understand:

[image: Second potential leak]

Comment: Where is it warning of a leak? The analyzer can point it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you retain alloced `UITextView` which first used `alloc`, than `addSubview` , than `retain`. Share code when you create it maybe to be more sure.

So you should balance this

Try :

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITextView *tWeekDay;
```

or add

```
-(void)dealloc {
[tWeekDay removeFromSuperview];
[tWeekDay release];
[super dealloc];
```

}

Comment: And the object is just placed on XIB and then associated with `@property` and then `@synthesize`.

Comment: You shouldn't call `[super dealloc]` explicitly, the compiler handles it for you, see this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292119/custom-dealloc-and-arc-objective-c

Comment: You could also try changing the `assign` to `strong` or `weak` in the property declaration, assign should not be used for pointers. @RickOn

Comment: Lol I jus noticed this question is over two years old. :D Well, ehm.